# How to import/export database from PouchDB

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

How to import/export database from local PouchDB database?
I need save my local database and open it in different platform.
There is no CouchDB on server side.

Answer (score 19):

There are features coded by the amazing @nolanlawson. Not only you can import/export it, you can do all sorts of things with it. Just awesome.

**PouchDB Replication Stream**
https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-replication-stream

> ReadableStreams and WritableStreams for PouchDB/CouchDB replication.
>   Basically, you can replicate two databases by just attaching the
>   streams together. This has many uses: Dump a database to a file, and
>   then load that same file into another database. Do a quick initial
>   replication by dumping the contents of a CouchDB to an HTTP endpoint,
>   which is then loaded into a PouchDB in the browser. Replicate over web
>   sockets? Over bluetooth? Over NFC? Why not? Since the replication
>   stream is just JSON plaintext, you can send it over any transport
>   mechanism. Periodically backup your database.

And **PouchDB.load** to import:
https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-load

> Client-side tools for loading a dump from a CouchDB/PouchDB database.
>   For dumping, check out pouchdb-dump-cli to dump from the command line,
>   or pouchdb-replication-stream to dump from within your Node.js
>   application. This method is typically much faster than standard
>   replication, because it uses fewer HTTP requests. So it's a great way
>   to quickly load an initial state for your database.

Comment: Thanks for the kudos. :) Also check out this blog post explaining how to dump and load SQLite files: https://pouchdb.com/2016/04/28/prebuilt-databases-with-pouchdb.html

Answer (score 8):

To export, why don't you just load all docs and save them into a file?

```
db.allDocs({include_docs: true, attachments: true}).then(JSON.stringify);
```

Comment: it not working blob type data ,it stores just raw data only.do you know any solution for that?

Comment: Thank you, i integrated that solution, but i have a problem, documents deleted not sync (i exported documents deleted and imported by bulkDocs(data, {new_edits: true}), but not sync, something idea?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution, as @mrded said, is to use batch operations:

```
<button onClick={handleExport}>Export</button>
<input type="file" onChange={handleImport}/>
```

```
function handleExport () {
  db.allDocs({include_docs: true}, (error, doc) => {
    if (error) console.error(error);
    else download(
      JSON.stringify(doc.rows.map(({doc}) => doc)),
      'tracker.db',
      'text/plain'
    );
  });
}

function handleImport ({target: {files: [file]}}) {
  if (file) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = ({target: {result}}) => {
      db.bulkDocs(
        JSON.parse(result),
        {new_edits: false}, // not change revision
        (...args) => console.log('DONE', args)
      );
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  }
}
```

Also check the [download](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30832210/7138254) function.

Comment: Thank you, i integrated that solution, but i have a problem, documents deleted not sync (i exported documents deleted and imported by bulkDocs(data, {new_edits: true}), but not sync, something idea?