# How can I copy pouchdb 0000003.log file to Ionic 5 and retrieve the data?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, pouchdb

My scenario is to use pouch db data in ionic and I successfully added pouch db package to ionic and created a sample and it worked fine. Now I have a scenario I have the below file
[image]

000003.log in which I have all the data, but in ionic it is storing in the indexdb so how can I use this 000003.log data and copy it to indexeddb or is there any way copy the contents ?

Below is my app code

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

private database: any;
private myNotes: any;

constructor() {
  this.database = new PouchDB('my-notes');
}

public addNote(theNote: string): Promise<string> {
  const promise = this.database
    .put({
      _id: ('note:' + (new Date()).getTime()),
      note: theNote
    })
    .then((result): string => (result.id));

  return (promise);
}

getMyNotes() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let _self = this;
    this.database.allDocs({
      include_docs: true,
      attachments: true
    }).then(function (result) {
      // handle result
      _self.myNotes = result.rows;
      console.log("Results: " + JSON.stringify(_self.myNotes));
      resolve(_self.myNotes);

    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  });
}
```

How to export/import the existing database in ionic app? Do I have to store in file system or indexeddb?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import/export database from PouchDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37229561/how-to-import-export-database-from-pouchdb)

Comment: Not entirely but it gave me some idea

Comment: What is your use case? Is this a DB that lives in a project filesystem, and you want to deploy the app with that canned database? Really need more detail because there are many options, but without your explicit use case any answer would be a wild guess.

Answer (score 0):

By default PouchDb will use IndexDb, so its doing it correctly. If you want to change storage you need to setup a different adapter.

> I don't see *where you set up the options for the local adapter*, so I think `you are missing the local & adapter setup options` to support it

[image: how to setup PouchDb with Iconic locally and Remote]

---

> Now use the correct adapter you want [PouchDB here](https://pouchdb.com/adapters.html)

[image: PouchDb adapter setup]

Comment: The problem isn't adapter related. OP has a canned database in his project folder and wants to serialize that db and then deserialize it to an application instance.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an Ionic 5/Angular repo that demonstrates how to take a local pouchdb as described in the OP and load it as a default canned database in the app.

https://github.com/ramblin-rose/canned-pouch-db

The hurdles were not huge, but I encountered some problems along the way, mainly some wrangling with respect to pouchdb's es modules and module default exports.

Specifically, the documentation for [pouchdb-replication-stream](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-replication-stream) is not helpful for incorporation for Ionic5/Angular.  I assumed the import

```
import ReplicationStream from 'pouchdb-replication-stream';
```

Would just work, but unfortunately at runtime this dread error would popup

> Type Error: Promise is not a constructor

Ouch!  That's a show stopper.  However I came across the pouchdb-replication-stream issue [es modules](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-replication-stream/issues/69)

Which prompted the solution:

```
import ReplicationStream from 'pouchdb-replication-stream/dist/pouchdb.replication-stream.min.js';
```

Anyway the highlights of the repo are 'can-a-pouchdb.js' and 'data.service.ts'.

##### can-a-pouchdb.js

This script will create a local node pouchdb and then serialize that db to app/assets/db, which is later loaded by the ionic app.

The important bits of code:

```
 // create some trivial docs
    const docs = [];
    const dt = new Date(2021, 6, 4, 12, 0, 0);
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++, dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + i)) {
      docs[i] = {
        _id: "note:" + dt.getTime(),
        note: `Note number ${i}`,
      };
    }
    // always start clean - remove database dump file
    fs.rmdirSync(dbPath, { recursive: true });

    PouchDB.plugin(replicationStream.plugin);
    PouchDB.adapter(
      "writableStream",
      replicationStream.adapters.writableStream
    );
    const db = new PouchDB(dbName);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(docs));
    await db.bulkDocs(docs);
    //
    // dump db to file.
    //
    fs.mkdirSync(dumpFileFolder, { recursive: true });
    const ws = fs.createWriteStream(dumpFilePath);
    await db.dump(ws);
```

To recreate the canned database run the following from the CL:

```
$ node can-a-pouchdb.js
```

##### data.service.ts

Here's how the app's pouchdb is hydrated from the canned database. Take note the db is using the memory adapter, because as a demo app *not* persisting the db is desirable.

```
public async init(): Promise<void> {
    if (this.db === undefined) {
      PouchDB.plugin(PouchdbAdapterMemory);
      PouchDB.plugin(ReplicationStream.plugin);
      this.db = new PouchDB(DataService.dbName, { adapter: 'memory' });
      // if the db is empty, hydrate it with the canned db assets/db
      const info = await this.db.info();
      if (info.doc_count === 0) {
        //load the asset into a string
        const cannedDbText = await this.http
          .get('/assets/db/mydb.dump.txt', {
            responseType: 'text',
          })
          .toPromise();
        // hydrate the db
        return (this.db as any).load(
          MemoryStream.createReadStream(cannedDbText)
        );
      }
    }
```