# Populating a new PouchDB database efficiently

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am new to PouchDB and I am trying to simply pull data from my remote CouchDB database to a new local PouchDB database.

The following works of course:

```
PouchDB.replicate(remote, local, { live: false, retry: false })
```

but it is just crazy how slow it is! I take it is because it's doing so many http requests sequentially.

As an optimisation I thought:

> OK, let's fetch the data first in one HTTP request with `remote.allDocs` then use `local.bulkDocs` to insert the docs in the local db

but it's not equivalent to replicating the db, and the `_rev` field in the docs will make `bulkDocs` fail.

What should I do?

### More details

#### about the database

- there currently are 1202 documents
- there use to be about 4000
- I just added a couple of revisions to each document

##### about the performances:

- it takes about 2 seconds to run `remote.allDocs({include_docs: true})`. The output is 1.15 MB
- it takes **1 minute** to run `PouchDB.replicate(remote, local, { live: false, retry: false })`, the output is about 5 MB
- it takes about 24 seconds to add a `filter: doc => !doc._deleted`
- and about 20 seconds to add a `filter: 'new_device/excludeDeletedDocs'` with the same filter as before in a design document

About the replication lasting 1 minute: it surprised me, I thought it was faster than that, but it's how long it takes now.

#### about the app

- there is one database per user
- they can access it through multiple devices, online and offline
- most docs are small, are edited a couple of times and are relatively short lived
- a big minority of them last virtually forever
- a fraction of them can be bigger and can be edited many many times.

Comment: You may find some relief with [PouchDB Replication Streams](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-replication-stream), see case #2 [here](https://cnpmjs.org/package/pouchdb-replication-stream).  Also [here's a way to preload a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68105040/how-can-i-copy-pouchdb-0000003-log-file-to-ionic-5-and-retrieve-the-data/68245289#68245289) for hybrid apps

Comment: As an afterthought, how many revisions is the db retaining? Often lowering that threshold to a reasonable level will have a noticeable impact for some databases. See [revs_limit](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_database).  Without specific information regarding your database you may not get a definitive answer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks I'll investigate that tomorrow morning. I have about 1000 docs in my database, they haven't been updated once since I'm importing old data from a previous version of the app, but I've played around with the remote DB, there use to be 4000 items, the there are tombstones indeed. However I expect that a normal db in a real app would have a certain number of revisions anyway.

Comment: indeed - but a 1000 docs is trivial, unless there is an endless stream of revs especially if the docs are largish.  Follow up with an edit of your OP with more info!

Comment: At least sounds like you want to at least use [options.filter](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#replication) to purge deleted docs.

Comment: "1.15Mo ... 5 Mo" what is "Mo"?

Comment: Sorry, this is a French designation. A megaoctet is just a megabyte (with one byte being 8 bits which is the case most of the time). Anyway, it's a vert small db for the time it takes to sync it.

Comment: Is it true that the initial database which you are replicating to a client device is fairly static, in other words is it mainly a starting point?

Comment: The initial database is representative of data that can be produced by one user during one year. The amount of data should grow at a decreasing rate, then linearly. I expect that at some point some databases will have multiple users with more frequent edits, but nothing crazy. That being said, even a single user can manage to create conflicts when on multiple devices which can go offline.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237653/discussion-between-ramblinrose-and-geoffrey).